# Traces outside polygons after merging several polygons together

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, merge, dissolve

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1

I have a polygon shapefile for areas upstream of 5 monitoring sites. I used `dissolve`and `merge` to merge all these polygons together. You can [download the resulting shapefile from here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w9ppj7ubced4i45/AAAa6wOZw77wk7NSMUx-Z13Ga?dl=0).

I used this shapefile in `R v. 3.2.5` for further analysis. In the result of this analysis, below, there was a line cutting through the polygons

[image]

I checked the shapefile again in ArcMap 10.3.1 to find that after merging, there were traces outside the polygons.

[image]

I tried to remove them but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem using

Editor -> More Editing Tools -> Advanced Editing -> Explode Multipart Features